# PHP Target Rows to Change Background Color

Tags: php, html, css

this is my code for a multiplication table.
By combining PHP and HTML/CSS I need to make every alternating rows background color white or grey.

I've thought of using a row and using `%2==1 and %2==0 to` figure out the odd and even rows but how would i target those rows to make a id or class to target on my css file?
Where would I insert this code at?

```
<?php
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th></th>';
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++)
        echo '<th>'.$x.'</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    for ($y = 1; $y <= 9; $y++)
    {   
        echo '<tr><th>'.$y.'</th>';
        for ($z = 1; $z <= 9; $z++)
        {   
            echo '<td>'.($y * $z).'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: `td:nth-child(even) { background: #f5f5f5 } td:nth-child(odd) { background: #ddd }`

Comment: @mdesdev You again! You should make this an answer, it's the best way to go about it.

Comment: @DrydenLong hahaha I know, I'm doing something right now, busy, just checking from time to time new questions and making comments. Take it and post it if you wish, elaborate a little ;)

Comment: @mdesdev SO should make team accounts haha

Comment: @DrydenLong hahahahahaha true ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dryden Long comments, best is CSS, but if you do need do it with php, you could do:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th></th>';
for ($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++)
    echo '<th>'.$x.'</th>';
echo '</tr>';
for ($y = 1; $y <= 9; $y++)
{   
    echo '<tr class="'. ( ($y%2 == 0 ) ? 'even' : 'odd' ).'"><th>'.$y.'</th>';
    for ($z = 1; $z <= 9; $z++)
    {   
        echo '<td>'.($y * $z).'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

and then you only have to add the CSS classes, and all will be working.

```
table tr.even { background-color: blue }
table tr.odd  { background-color: red }
```

Comment: The whole point was to practice html/css manipulation with php.
This was very helpful, and I also learned the use of ternary conditionals from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No need to assign classes with PHP when CSS can style alternate elements just fine. Using `nth-child` you can style alternative rows pretty easily.

```
tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background: #f5f5f5;
} 
tr:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9dLE/)

And here is more info on the `nth-child` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<tr class ="' . ( $y % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd' ) . '"><th>'.$y.'</th>';
```

You can use the ternary operator to insert a class

condition ? if true : if false;